# Odoo v17: Automation Rules - Trigger is missing?

Tags: automation, odoo

in Odoo 17 i want to create an Automation Rule for Create only? i can see there is an On Save trigger but it works on both Create and Update too. I want it to Execute Code on Create only. it was present in earler versions, why is missing in 17?

how to create Automation Rule specifically for Create only to assign a value after concatenation of 2 fields and a last+1 value using Execute Code ?

please guide.

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is still a trigger for "On Create", but its name has been tweaked and it is under a different heading. You should be able to use "After creation" in the same way.

You can find this menu/form by enabling developer mode, then going to *Settings > Technical > Automation > Automation Rules*.

[image: Screenshot of Automation Rules form view]

Comment: thank you @travisw for reply, in Developer mode i can't see after Email Events -> Custom and the Timing Conditions is not present, i am using Enterprise version. will check again and if its not an "overlook" i will share screenshot. as a way around i used condition in code " if not record.create_date: " ... regards

Comment: thank you again for your help, its there, i missed because of "Timing Conditions" it would be better these options will be under Like:  Transactions -> On Create etc. anyway, its their own business.